# Some calculation about Chern connection

Tags: complex-geometry, hermitian-manifolds

The Chern connection is the unique connection satisfying $\nabla^{0,1}=\bar{\partial}$ and
$$
\partial_k\langle u, v\rangle=\left\langle\nabla_k u, v\right\rangle+\left\langle u, \nabla_{\bar{k}} v\right\rangle .
$$
It can be written as
$$
\begin{aligned}
\nabla_{\bar{k}} u^\alpha & =\partial_{\bar{k}} u^\alpha, \\
\nabla_k u^\alpha & =\partial_k u^\alpha+u^\beta A_{k \beta}{ }^\alpha, \quad A_{k \beta}{ }^\alpha=\partial_k H_{\beta \bar{\nu}} H^{\bar{\nu} \alpha},
\end{aligned}
$$
or without indices as
$$
\nabla=\left(\partial+\partial H H^{-1}\right)+\bar{\partial} .
$$
I want to know how to verify that $$\nabla J =0.$$

Comment: This is equivalent to say that your metric is Kähler.

Comment: Thanks but this is Chern connection not Levi-Civita connection.

Comment: I learned that to make the levi-civita connection preserve the complex structure, the metric should be kahler.

Comment: It is not clear what do you mean by $J$, but I guess it is the complex structure in the bundle. Then you are asking how to verify that the Chern connection is complex linear. There is no reason to verify this, it is complex linear by definition (its structure group is $U(n)$).